# How to debug soap web services?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

If I have a server sitting somewhere that is not returning the correct information to a client that uses async methods to communicate with it, how do I debug this with soap?

I mean, atleast with rest I can just type in a web address inside a browser and see on the screen the xml response. But how is debugging usually done with soap?

Note, my client is c#/wpf and the server is java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have look at [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). I usually use it to develop and debug soap based web services.

Comment: this looks like more of a unit testing type tool, would I be able to call a remote method on it and _see results_ of that method?

Comment: also, how would authentication take place? I believe most of our services require some kind of user token in order to retrieve data

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned soapUI is great tool if you want to test communication manually. If you want to see what exactly happens between your application and the service use [Fiddler](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/14/Monitoring-HTTP-Output-with-Fiddler-in-NET-HTTP-Clients-and-WCF-Proxies).